# Show weekly statistic for variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a nested model for two locations. I use a method to count the distance between these two locations. I'd like to take statistics to count all the distances weekly and show it in a view like this:

```
Week 1 - 80 kms / Week 2 - 32 kms
```

Could someone help me with it?

**@edit**

Getting distance:

```
<% @distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(@trip.locations.first, @trip.locations.last) %>
```

Trip model:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :locations

accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :trip

extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

end
```

Trips controller:

```
def index
@trips = Trip.all
@trip = Trip.new
2.times { location = @trip.locations.build }
end


def show
@trip = Trip.includes(:locations).find(params[:id])
end
```

And I get the locations from a field_for form

also routes:

```
resources :trips
root 'trips#index'
```

Comment: What kind of help you want? Write code? Reference for read?

Comment: It could be a piece of code, it could be a reference for read - I'd appreciate any help, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please share how your localizations are stored and how is distance counted)

Comment: @jestemkarol you should try something by self. Your question is probably too broad.

Comment: @Зелёный I just want some references how to do it, because I don't have any idea what can I use

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Just try something, make some research, google is your friend. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you asking how to save the weekly info and then compare it?  Also, do you mean location or localisation?  If you could also post your routes that may help since you will probably benefit from them being nested here.

Comment: @BrianKunzig Yes, exactly. Weekly info about all the distance made. I'm sorry, my mistake - locations, of course. Routes added to post.

Comment: Add the location routes as well.  If you're using resource routing for both, the locations resource should be nested in the trips resource.  Doing this will give immediate access to the trips id in your params hash which is probably needed.  Add the route, and the form that takes the data to your post so I know.